# Server request completing before AJAX beforeunload call

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, onbeforeunload

I have a Rails 4 chat app that is having a small timing issue. When the user is on the active chatting page and they want to leave, they should be notified by the app that they have current chats and they must verify that they wish to leave the page. I have this working using the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  if(jQuery('#chatListUL li').length > 0){
    return 'You have active sessions. Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
  }
}).unload(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/chat/chat_sessions/removeUserFromAll',
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
  });
});
```

This is working as expected and will remove the user from all of their current chats.

```
...
enrolled_chats = ChatSessionUserList.where(user_id: current_user.id)
enrolled_chats.each do |ec|
  chat_session = ec.chat_session
  ec.destroy
  if chat_session.users.length < 2
    chat_session.open = false
    chat_session.save
  ...
  end
end
```

However if the link to go back to the overview chat page that lists all current and pending chats is used to navigate away from the page, then the following is run in the controller on the server:

```
...
@current_filled_requests = ChatSession.where(open: true)
...
```

The problem is when the overview page loads, it counts all of the previous active chats as still open. Looking in the log, I can see the request to the server for the overview page completing before the AJAX request that was sent in the beforeunload action. So those chats that user just left are being put into the instance variable before being marked as closed.

How can I make sure the beforeunload call completes before the actual server request? I know I could put an AJAX call on the overview page that would load the active chats after the page had loaded; but I was hoping to avoid another call to the server.

Comment: are you testing it on local server? Because anyway there is no reliable method to send ajax request from unload or even beforeunload events and the user could still press his computer shutdown button

Comment: Yes, right now it's running on the rails server.